# php passing URL

Tags: php

I have this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/get_url.php?ID=100&Link=http://www.test.com/page.php?l=1&m=7
```

When I print `$_GET['Link']`, I see only `http://www.test.com/page.php?l=1`.

Where is `&m=7`?

Comment: why don't you try print_r($_GET);

Comment: `&m=7` is part of the "main" URL `http://www.xxx.com/get_url.php...`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to pass an url as a GET parameter, you'll have to URL-encode it.

The problem is, the server sees `&` as ending the `Link` parameter. This means you're actually getting:

```
$_GET['ID'] = '100';
$_GET['Link'] = 'http://www.test.com/page.php?l=1';
$_GET['m'] = '7';
```

What you want to do is use `urlencode`. Example:

```
$link = 'http://sample.com/hello?a=5&b=6&d=7';
$address = 'http://site.com/do_stuff.php?link='.urlencode($link)
```

External references:

- [urlencode in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: Great answer. Let me just quickly add that when you retrieve the value, you'll want to use urldecode(): `$link = urldecode($_GET['Link'];` :)

Comment: Actually you don't need to `urldecode`; that's automatically handled for you by PHP.

Comment: Is it? That's nice, thanks for correcting me then, I wasn't aware of this one.

Answer (score 1):

It's a separate value. If you pass it this way, the GET values are:

```
ID=100
Link=http://www.test.com/page.php?l=1
m=7
```

The `&` character separates values passed by GET.

In order to pass the entire thing, you need to encode it properly (see Sebastian's answer).

Answer (score -1):

(see sebastian's answer).The server sees & as the ending parameter so u won't get the values after &.If u want to get the entire thing u need to encode the entire link using "function urlencode()" before passing the parameters